# Read non-specified format file data

Tags: c++

I have a problem reading file data packed as binary resource. I have something like this

```
7ë?Vý˝‹ĺ”>˙†J˙l$í?źÔ=ć$ľ>˙†J˙(çî?Yý˝ć$ľ>˙†J˙'Šč?[ý˝"6?˙†J˙KÓć?[YČ="6?˙†J˙…?Ů?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙4Ą×?ĄŰŞ=fË$?˙†J˙ĚúĹ?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙r„Ä?s˛…=n8?˙†J˙Ôž°?[ý˝.2??˙†J˙?š?$>Í<n8?˙†J˙ÜB›?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙#ţ‡?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙}ű†?eâ;fË$?˙†J˙gq?[ý˝"6?˙†J˙Ëšo?Đuő»"6?˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝_Yż>˙†J˙ľ\?P‰Ľ_Yż>˙†J˙: W?[ý˝ ÓS>˙†J˙JeU?@3ŁĽ ÓS>˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝Í#=˙†J˙ľ\?
```

It should be numeric data 1 float - 4 bytes.

it should be "1.8376168"

First 4 bytes of file converted to hex is

```
07 37 EB 3F
```

I need some help with converting this to float.

I managed to do this using memcpy.
Here is a code
(You can't see first character before 7 and it's [BELL] it works in VS)

```
void using_memcpy(const char* s, size_t slen) {
float* f = new float[slen / sizeof(float)];
memcpy(f, s, slen / sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));
for (size_t i = 0; i < slen / sizeof(float); ++i) {
    printf("%zu = %f\n", i, f[i]);
}
delete f;
```

}

```
           std::string ch = "7ë?";

       using_memcpy(ch.c_str(), ch.size());
```

Comment: `memcpy` from the first 4 bytes into (the address of) a float. You may need to swap endian.

Comment: @Dominique Why do you talk about 18376168 while OP asks about 1.8?

Comment: Oh? I thought this was a thousand/million separator :-)

Comment: You need the 'non-specified' specification of the file format. Without that it is anybody's guess. You should return this assignment to sender.

Comment: I managed to do this using memcpy. Copying first 4 bits to float was what I was talking about. File format doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is the binary representation of IEEE 754 floating point numbers, which it looks like it is, you can `memcpy` that data into a float variable.

You may need to do endianness conversion, depending on the platform you're compiling for.

[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCS0gAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAqHhUSyx8WYatpj2BQxCBEzEBFk%2BfoF2mA4Z9Y0ERZExcQnSCg1NLTlctmN9YQOlQxUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmO25Oo8SYrKfYJhoAgrv7h5gnZ5dhwLf3T2Z7DAOXmOpzcyE%2BRh%2Bj2egNe7zcjWITAAnlC/gCgSCzmJgCRCAgWGiYZi3qDooQiY8APRUo5UYioFhHBAEAhJBQgGmMAB0yCSSSuVDijE2vMZVIA7lS%2BUkqQwfHE8MgqdFkQRMAoJUwkr91SwkgZ1aDRugQCAwurgEjaEcACpotAMUaYVQCu1HVXqzXaiC2o4ANzEXkwSyODFQLs2SQIvxMAHYrI8jsmjqMmI5kAB9JgKJRNCAms0IHOZrwMPAAR2DmdQ0W0nQImauAo1jAatQUmf9oPtO2wpBOZjMfpYKLDqAIzKY/reSSY6HwRg9hAU5jMS1OiYeKaOTC8RADQcwTcwLaUgnTGXeABFUwRTSByY3RKNjfezYiUW%2BH57MAO0gAXpgqBUL6G59rcECBt4Iabr8O6FiASJGBqZpXDOxBKFBR4nmebaXgI4FbjuVwEOsDB3j%2BhCZi%2BMZnL22DYTBuFXOe7YZERsZxtesaPBaRyjmEEAbtCCbwSmjqjJRZoQsARxIhKmboOmTA3oOZhxiYbg7CYDxWDsABiABqWk6RYPFuFYACcPHYGYJgABwaCYFhWVpkguU8dmOc5Nk/JZJhWW53lObpGgAFJadZVm0AAJKZuk8YZ9xWG4ACsnkJVZHk7BZHkOXG8VuB5Fh3BBAVBSYIXOQ8EVRYFVkQAlDyadpullQZACaCXmfVfnFY5hXuS5ZV3BVwX2aFtWReNYDbOlYXDQ5SUGSYaWpWZFnWTxaVuGu/inKt41VZNNV1eNADSWU6QNBWHWtFjdbde25Wte1DgdyXHdVYUzdFJ0%2Bbpn1HRlDwdQ9PVbYF15UAlDkWPFX3/T9019dlS0eW1VmaV9%2BWYxlFjOQtVllTDcMI/d32nb9aPDVZTxtRYDMlW5yXrZDfXXgwDmU8j1Oo%2BNxAA6FJNwzlBmrhVVgo59XM80jDXC2df2K1j%2BMjVp9mE/d7OM1DNncvZyUK5VKPnf9X2g1wh2I2NOnLaC3O84rZsq5VWMBT9TM6xtLn63Lzum/z5uK/8WmgzpKPW2zvu9RVZNtfDiNHXzgMC/93Hhy51tm4dmDNUbFiw4nFMmxNach0FwAVj7HPx29%2B2B%2BXU2V25JdZw8XCoJTHlWRoXhZ1Z1tuFrVi7Y3ZdKzT40APJi2tK0Q3rnOZk9BMvWNqct27bclXc4%2BGcoU/awN5mr1nFgb7TrtoyARwAOq18v8cnFjOxCP5W/K2j4WYHIh0AAEboZQcsPEqt5rof3Kl/ae0U56Jw8mlReutNqczhjxMOr0qYVx3sNUqDdkpDjgtCJMKZ%2BDEALHgICmZJx4HQKoNSzkdjER3CmOhDDQSnFvBABSSkVLckApgYSRwAC0RxJCcVIawo47DBz6VvBI8SyZ4wsOkWmDM2ZcxxAIJQoCIFqC0FQOmUMXCuHiMkU8KRrC8BUCOJJdUrpiBHALO%2BEArg8CGDNMwRwM4bxmMQu4zxj48DABEtuaRJwxJWIiUcGkYZMCYHQEcA83okhHECQwcIuYlExJkYIHYZgaHJMwPqYh4TcnSRAGwFgfJkRNTMP4PUSQBy8OUg0bkbSmDCOsDI%2BhA5FHMJyTEppalfypIgE0ixFTkxUEMemOkZTpmVOqbU%2Bp/gqADnMI0kpzTzGLOmYhNA%2B54SgjpCcs4lTXC0H2dI%2BMPFokpmqEoIZKYVEvOkbMoxk5YaDIeWo1xKykh1K2Rs%2BSTBFKdI6SpbplhemqH6VMg5rijmTk4Rc2xaK3CXIYOga5vzymsLuTkololrwcBWLQTgaVeB%2BA4FoUgqBODvSsLChQawNikn%2BDwUgBBNDkpWAAaxAGlSolKOCSBpXyhlnBeAckqLyul5LSBwFgDARAKBGRJDoHEcglA0D6m1fEYAXAzBTBoLQdUmFKDRCleSZgxBkScG5fqtgggZ4MFoI6xVpAsCjiMOIb1%2BArhdBnByb1LpOj7i2PSi01QpW0DwNEJEDqPBYClQQYgeAWBOqVbMpgwAFBGTwJgCUM8kiMBzTIQQIgxDsCkFW%2BQSg1BSt0FMAwRgUDWGsPoRNHJIArFQNGDIYaREmi4aYSw1gKiyuqA2DILgcUTD8FMEIcwShlFyKkdIAgl2bvyBkfo66hhTA6F0AQPRxieFaHoU9tQL2zGKIMeIJ6Zi7pfb0Q9T6JArDZesTYegM0JJzRSqlkrvWMo4KoBy/gRH%2BEkEcYAyBkBHBNdyLgzjmXdqOLgQgJBBw7CmEcDwBr6BON2FwJYvAFVaCWIK4VorOAStINmkVpBaX0og7KkA8q%2BUrBVeqtYbJ9y6ogPqrVpGIisC2FBmDcGENIZQ2YNDvBEm4czaaM1sga3iHrfwQQigVDqG9a20gEokRJGA/oUDbGpUQZnvuJIxyQJHBk7B%2BDiHkOofQxAYj4m4j4Yo1R3jKwEDXCwPEYSVnxW8BY5UdjvBOO2G4zy4LpAhWsbFTsMDHGZUpcVbRqLZhssJdy9R/lpAMJpGcJIIAA%3D%3D)

```
// read this from a file and store it in some container.
// this is just a std::string for an easier example
const std::string raw_data = "7ë?Vý˝‹ĺ”>˙†J˙l$í?źÔ=ć$ľ>˙†J˙(çî?Yý˝ć$ľ>˙†J˙'Šč?[ý˝\"6?˙†J˙KÓć?[YČ=\"6?˙†J˙…?Ů?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙4Ą×?ĄŰŞ=fË$?˙†J˙ĚúĹ?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙r„Ä?s˛…=n8?˙†J˙Ôž°?[ý˝.2??˙†J˙?š?$>Í<n8?˙†J˙ÜB›?[ý˝n8?˙†J˙#ţ‡?[ý˝fË$?˙†J˙}ű†?eâ;fË$?˙†J˙gq?[ý˝\"6?˙†J˙Ëšo?Đuő»\"6?˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝_Yż>˙†J˙ľ\?P‰Ľ_Yż>˙†J˙: W?[ý˝ ÓS>˙†J˙JeU?@3ŁĽ ÓS>˙†J˙OÄ]?[ý˝Í#=˙†J˙ľ\?";

for(size_t idx = 0;
    idx <= (raw_data.size() - 4);
    idx += 4)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4);

    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big)
    {
        // need to swap endianness
        int32_t temp;
        std::memcpy(&temp, raw_data.data() + idx, 4);
        temp = byteswap(temp); //check the compiler explorer link for the implementation
        float f;
        std::memcpy(&f, &temp, 4);
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        float f;
        std::memcpy(&f, raw_data.data() + idx, 4);
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    }
}
```